# Generate openapi v3.0 specifications from python code

Tags: python, ruby, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I am using a python API that has been auto generated by others with [OpenAPI Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/) and I do not have access to the yaml file. Now I need to use some of the routes/endpoints in some existing Ruby code. At the moment I am using the debug to track the actual requests and then recreate them in Ruby. This is quite painful.

Is it possible to reconstruct the openAPI specification yaml file and then use it to generate [Ruby code](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/ruby)?

Comment: You mean they generated the Python API via the OpenAPI Generator but threw away the `yaml`?

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek yes, I do not have access to the yaml unfortunately